# use crossbar ggplot2

Tags: eclipse, r, cran

I am plotting bar charts for climate different models. I would like make a plot comparing models to observations. The climate models will plotted as bar (geom_bar()) but I would like to have the observation crossbars.

The script below makes a plot but there is something (upside down triangle) that is plotted above the graph. What is wrong with this script?, Am I missing something?

```
ch<-structure(list(Month = structure(c(4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", 
"Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), GCM1 = c(169.5, 157.19, 90.07, 42.97, 13.24, 1.56, 
2.53, 5.99, 14.92, 46.35, 88.23, 138.02), GCM2 = c(215.01, 193.37, 
131.14, 41.48, 7.63, 0.94, 0.81, 0.78, 1.88, 15.95, 99.58, 188.16
), GCM3 = c(164.83, 158.82, 97.5, 29.27, 5.47, 2.14, 3.34, 0.85, 
9.94, 16.9, 57.21, 117.05), OBS = c(142.25, 138.59, 59.95, 26.48, 
2.61, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.72, 11.64, 38.75, 119.82)), .Names = c("Month", 
"GCM1", "GCM2", "GCM3", "OBS"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")

ch$Month<-month.abb
ch$Month<-factor(ch$Month, levels=c(month.abb[10:12],month.abb[1:9]), ordered=TRUE)

chm<-melt(ch, id="Month")

cbPalette1 <- cbbPalette <- c("#D55E00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73","#0072B2", "#CC79A7","#000000")

p<-ggplot(data=chm,aes(x=factor(Month),y=value,group=variable,fill=variable))+geom_bar(subset = .(variable != "OBS"),stat="identity",position=position_dodge())+
                scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette1)+
                geom_crossbar(subset = .(variable == "OBS"),aes(ymin = min(value), ymax = max(value)), col="gray30",fatten=3)
```

.......

Many thanks in advance

BHH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. You are overriding the group aesthetic to just be `variable`, so
   in the crossbar, it is ignoring the different `x` values (treating
   it as continuous) and that is giving a weird crossbar.
2. I think you just want the bar itself, not any extent around it.
   If so, you want to set `ymin` and `ymax` to the central value, not
   to the range of all central values.

Making both those changes:

```
p<-ggplot(data=chm,
          aes(x = Month,
              y = value,
              fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(subset = .(variable != "OBS"), 
           stat="identity",
           position=position_dodge()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette1)+
  geom_crossbar(subset = .(variable == "OBS"),
                aes(ymin = value, ymax = value), 
                col="gray30", fatten=3)
```

[image]